# How to best set dataset fields to non null value

Tags: delphi

I have a client dataset where fields are updated
when messages come in from external communication channels.
Not all fields are updated by every message.

The dataset is displayed by a dbgrid.
Some fields are displayed using OnDrawColumnCell events.

During the startup phase, before recirds exist,
messages can be received in any order.
After each post,
the OnDrawColumnCell event is generated,
BUT not all fields have been written yet, and are null.

The null fields cause exceptions when OnDrawColumCell wants to use them.
I need to make sure all fields are always non null,
for instance by filling all with default values when creating the record.

Finally to my question(s).

Q1: Is defaulting all fields on record creation the best way?
    It requires maintenance discipline when things change.

Q2: Is try/except a good way to catch this in the event?
    It too requires discipline, to catch all.

Q3: Is there a better way to avoid this issue?

Q4: Am I not thinking properly?

Thanks for any suggestions,

Anders Johansson

Comment: Why not use `if Column.Field.Value <> null  ...` in `OnDrawColumnCell`? Or I misunderstood?

Comment: That works, but I would prefer to handle this once, when records are created, not every time the fields are used.

Comment: Make up your mind what you're asking. If you want to assign the field a default value, use the `TField.DefaultExpression` and set it up when you add the field and don't worry about it. If you don't want to do that, use the `if not Column.Field.IsNull` in `OnDrawColumnCell`. You can't say *I don't want to assign a default value to the field, because I might forget in the future, but I also don't want to depend on the alternative.*. My choice would be to use the `DefaultExpression` and **not** use a `try..except`, so that the exception raised would tell me I forgot to assign the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ClientDataSet's OnNewRecord event to set the initial values for fields:

```
procedure CDS1.OnNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet.FieldByName('SomeField').AsString := '';  // this is NOT 
    // the same as leaving the field in its initial, NULL, state
end;
```

Q1: Is defaulting all fields on record creation the best way? It requires maintenance discipline when things change.

You should do that anyway, if you don't want undefined behaviour when NULL values are encountered.

Q2: Is try/except a good way to catch this in the event? It too requires discipline, to catch all.

Not particularly, because the Application exception handler will catch it anyway.

Q3: Is there a better way to avoid this issue?

Yes, see OnNewRecord, above.

Q4: Am I not thinking properly?

Yes, imo you're not.  In particular, regardless of OnNewRecord, you need to expect the unexpected (aka "defensive programming"), so heed Val Marinov's advice about OnDrawCell.

Comment: I like the OnNewRecord solution.
It seems to do exactly what I want.
I should have thought of that one myself, it is so obvious now.

Concerning try/except.
I like it since lets me silently handle the issue instead
of throwing a difficult to understand Delphi generated exception
in the users face.
Is it bad practice to handle exceptions silently?

Concerning "defensive programming".
I totally agree that this must be used.
But to what extent?
I prefer having a robust solution in one central place,
and minimize the need to have multiple (forgotten?)
tests scattered throughout the application.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's tricky to balance centralized exception handling with handlers for specific things.  In my main application (for in-house use), I used (before I retired) to use centralised exception handling and logging; the logs were written to a central network location and it was very handy because I could fix most problems within a few minutes of the first user tripping over them.